# Huge content download time for a resource from service worker cache

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am intercepting and returning a resource from service worker cache. It takes around 300-400ms to download the content as per Google Chrome devtools. I checked in Firefox, the download is instant.

[image: Huge content download time]

I expected that download time to be a lot smaller since no network is involved. I intercept the fetch with the usual `match` function:

```
event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(response => response)
);
```

Is there something wrong I am doing in the way I intercept and return the resource from cache?

Comment: Note, the devtools network monitor in firefox does not show timing information for requests intercepted by a service worker.  So it may not show any bar chart, but its probably not "instant".  You can use the performance API to get the timings for the resource, though.

Comment: Also, if you are using `ignoreSearch:true` with cache.match() in chrome there is a known performance issue:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=682677

Comment: @BenKelly yes, you are right, Firefox doesn't show the time. I mean it feels real fast as compared to Chrome. And I am not using `ignoreSearch:true`.

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible test case using glitch.com or something that would be helpful.

Comment: I created a chrome user profile without extensions and when there I saw the normal behaviour without the big content download time. I haven't identified yet which extension is causing this.

Comment: Is your rule Network first? In this case, it can make sense

Comment: @aral-roca Nope. It checks with cache first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solutions from this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ruuIcaBOKKI):

> - Delete your cache and cookies
> - Use incognito mode If this helps then temporarily disable your extensions to identify which one is causing the rendering problem. To
>     do this go to chrome://extensions and uncheck Enabled for each
>     extension one by one.
> - Reset your browser settings
> - Turn off hardware acceleration by going to Menu > Settings > Advanced Settings > Under 'System' uncheck Use hardware acceleration
>     when available.